# Custom mega menu by overriding Topmenu.php

Tags: magento2, custom, megamenu

I can't find a good mega menu on the web. I want a mega menu which shows thumbnail categories directly in the dropdown menu.

But I can't find it, I tried many mega menu but they didn't work.

So I want to know if it's possible to do it myself, and if so, how to achieve it. Thanks

**EDIT**

It's inside the Topmenu.php file (in module-theme folder).

By default we have this :

```
            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                    $child->getName()
                ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
```

And I want something like this :

```
            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                    $child->getName()
                ) . '</span>'.$child->getThumbnail().'</a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
```

where $child->getThumbnail is the thumbnail of the category